# Deep learning-Flatten is one of the special form of Embedding?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, embedding, flatten

In Deep Learning,

The definition of Embedding is making data to dense vector.

Flatten is a widely used concept that makes data in a line. So, we can consider Flatten also return vector. Just except changing feature numbers.

So, Flatten is one of the special form of Embedding? is this logically right?

Flatten ⊂ Embedding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Flatten is a layer that takes input of higher dim i.e (d1,d2,...,dn) and flatten it out to 1d vector. This vector will have (d1 * d2 * ... * dn) elements. It doesn't learn anything. It just takes higher dim tensor and converts it to single dim tensor.

Embeddings on the other hand have learnable parameters which gets updated during the training. These parameters learn meaningful representation of the data.